# Symlink in ec2 /var/www/html/

Tags: git, symbolic-link, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm having problems with EC2 in the Amazon Cloud.

My steps:

- I have a symlink to the S3 in `/var/www/html`
- I update my code and upload the code with `git aws.push` in my environment (`var/www/html`)
- Thereafter, the symlink is gone.

I'm looking for the symlink at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure but I'm going to guess the `git aws.push` redeploys that directory by wiping it out and replacing it (as opposed to, say, running a `git pull`). Git allows you to version control symlinks. You might try adding it to the repo, even though it will be broken locally.